# What is the proper way to flatten a dictionary in Python, so that each key and list element is paired up?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have a dictionary object that looks like:

```
my_dict = {
    first_key: [{},{}],
    second_key: [{},{}],
    n_key: [{},{}, etc...]
}
```

I would like to flatten the object so that it now looks like:

```
{first_key: {object_1}, first_key: {object_2}; second_key, {object_1}, etc...}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Dict keys are unique

Comment: @DeepSpace I guess that's a typo

Comment: Your input dictionary is not in Python syntax. Your output dictionary is neither. Also you can not have the same key more than once in a dictionary.

Comment: Even if you could, how would you access the correct object from a key?

Comment: You cannot have it like that directly. What you can have is something like `[{first_key: first_list}, {first_key: second_list}, {second_key: second_list}]` etc.

Comment: @BradSolomon That's the problem. I have this object now but I am not sure how to flatten it further.

Comment: @DeepSpace, I did not know that was not a thing. I am making this object using list comprehension.

Comment: Why do you think you need to flatten it?

Comment: Maybe what you want is something like `[{"key": "first_key", "value": first_list}, {"key": "first_key", "value": second_list_object}, ...]`

Comment: @Barmar I am sending this object to a UI to display it as a list. Like a chart almost of like everything `first_key` has and etc.

Comment: @Barmar that's exactly what I want. How would I go about arranging the object like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. You can turn it until a flat list of key-value objects with nested loops:

```
result = []
for key, l in my_dict.items():
    for obj in l:
        result.append({"key": key, "value": obj})
```

The result will look like:

```
[{"key": "first_key", "value": {}},
 {"key": "first_key", "value": {}},
 {"key": "second_key", "value": {}},
 ...
]
```